# In Ext js how to highlight text in grid if it matches searching criteria

Tags: extjs4

I have one grid and text box. I want to highlight values in grid which matches with value in text field.

For example, in `firefox`, if you press `cntrl + F4`, you will see one text box and you write a value which you want to find. Firefox hightlights string mathing with this value.

Can we do like this in `extjs`? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example of exactly that here:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/live-search-grid.html

Comment: Hi Evan, I saw the link, its the same as i want. I copied all the code and created same file as in example. but the grid is not generating. There might be an error in required config. Can you please tell me how to use it?

Comment: I don't know what more you can need, there's a fully working example.

Comment: hmm.., My question to you was, where to put these files, but now i got it. Thanks.!

Answer (score 2):

Sandeep, the trick to the highlighting is actually in the `CSS`.
You can navigate to `../examples/ux/css/LiveSearchGridPanel.css` to find the following code:

`.x-livesearch-match {font-weight: bold; background-color: yellow; }`

You can add the CSS href to your index.html, or add this code to your css
Hope this is what you were able to figure out.